# Проблема при обращении к БД sqlite в Android 9

Tags: android

Есть приложение которое внутри себя содержит БД. При первом запуске эта база копируется и приложение ее использует. После копирования происходит обращение к БД используя обычный SELECT FROM. Очень долгое время это все работало. Но с выходом Android 9 пользователи стали присылать сообщения о краше приложения в момент запуска. Точнее оно и не открывается теперь. Может в новом Андроид еще какую фичу внедрили касаемо БД или копируемых файлов?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может создать эмулятор Android 9 в студии и посмотреть в чем там проблема, почитать стектрейс и добавить его в вопрос?

Comment: С удовольствием бы, но эмулятор не могу поставить на свой ПК. Процессор не поддерживает виртуализацию

Comment: Наверное изменился путь к файлу БД. Гляньте этот ответ на en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630708 - вдруг поможет.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо. Помогло решение из этого вопроса, правда другое, не то, что отмечено галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [ссылке woesss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476782/android-p-sqlite-no-such-table-error-after-copying-database-from-assets/50630708#50630708) нашел подходящее решение. Правда там есть ремарка, что могут быть побочные эффекты, но я пока их не заметил. Приложение стало запускаться на Android 9.

Переопределил метод:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```

добавил к нему `db.disableWriteAheadLogging();`

Как написал автор Ramon Canales:

> По-видимому, Android P меняет значение PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;

Хотя справка SQLite пишет, что по умолчанию `PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;`

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема возникла с Андроид 9.
Перестал видеть БД

Запрашивал БД так:

```
mSQL = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath2, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Изменил на:

```
mSQL = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath2, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Заработало...